# Add link to echo'd HTML from SQL data

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink

Back with another quick question. I have this code below which echo's out product names from a database. What I want to do is make the echoed out product names a link to another page called product.php, each link needs to have a unique ID, for example

```
<a href="product.php?id=1">Product Name</a>
```

How would I go about doing this? Many thanks. I will point out that I am very new to PHP.

```
<?php
//create an ADO connection and open the database
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->open("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\WebData\Northwind.mdb");

//execute an SQL statement and return a recordset
$rs = $conn->execute("SELECT product_name FROM Products");
$num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count();

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!$rs->EOF) //looping through the recordset (until End Of File)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     for ($i=0; $i <  $num_columns; $i++) {
         echo "<td>" . $rs->Fields($i)->value . "</td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     $rs->MoveNext();
}
echo "</table>";

//close the recordset and the database connection
$rs->close();
$rs = null;
$conn->close();
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Does your Products table have a unique ID field?

Comment: Sorry please see updated question.

Comment: I was going to id them using <a href="product.php?id=1">Product Name</a>

Comment: Posted an answer below, just make sure you have a unique ID field in the DB for Products first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Products table has a unique ID field called "id", change your select to:

```
$rs = $conn->execute("SELECT id, product_name FROM Products");
```

And when you want to create a link, use that field and pass it into the URL. So you'd have `product.php?id=<?= $thatIdField; ?>`.

Example code:

```
echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!$rs->EOF) //looping through the recordset (until End Of File)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     for ($i=0; $i <  $num_columns; $i++) {
         echo "<td><a href=\"product.php?id=" . $rs->Fields('id').value . "\">" . $rs->Fields($i)->value . "</a></td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     $rs->MoveNext();
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Now a complete idiotic question from me. How would I make that product a link using the code above? Can't think of the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: In the code above, you're looping through all the fields on the record, which is generic. You need to point to the specific ID field. I'm not familiar with ADODB's Field() syntax, but you might try, OUTSIDE THE LOOP:

Comment: `$rs->Fields('id');` (assuming that field is id)

Comment: echo "<td><a href='product.php?id=<?= $thatIdField; ?> . $rs->Fields($i)->value . "</td>"; ?

Comment: One sec, lemme write it up better

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about this! I am newbie.

Comment: Done. Not sure exact syntax for the Fields bit, but that should point you in the right direction.